# How to display data depending on country in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have a Django site that works perfectly and displays everything I want it to in the US. It automatically displays the data from the US data model.

What I want to be able to do is basically have an exact clone of my site, maybe under like mysite.com/canada for example, that displays the data from canada.

One approach was for me to just add in all the data into the database and add a field that says which country it's from, but I'd rather for each countries data to be in a completely different model.

With pure HTML/CSS this would be easy, I would just copy the entire site directory into a sub directory and that would be it for the country. Was wondering if there is something similiar I can do with Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you're describing you should probably be setting up parallel stacks and using either your DNS, Apache, your whatever your HTTP routing tech of choice is to do the separation.

Use a separate database, possibly even a separate server (or WSGI configuration), and keep your code clean.

Creating duplicate "models" based on the value of a field like you're describing breaks a lot of Python's DRY principles.